# Populating fields in a Matrix format

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, .net

I am trying to develop an accuracy assessment tool using ArcObjects. As an output I would like to show a matrix with the fields such as road ,land,water etc.  I just want to know how can I fetch unique values from the  raster value attribute table into a matrix format.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the sample inputs that would result in the example you provided?

Comment: I just want the row and column headers to be populated with unique values like road,building,trees and water. These attributes can be read from the attribute table of a raster file.

Comment: Then how does the Excel file come into play? It may seem simple to you but the question is not clear at all to me.

Comment: Thanks.I have edited the question now.Hope it clear now .Thank You.

Comment: What does the matrix represent and how should it be created? Describe a sample dataset you would use as an input and describe how it should be transformed into the desired output. We are not mind readers.

Comment: What part of problem are you having trouble with? Creating the VAT table, or populating it with values?

Comment: you matrix looks like a change analysis between two rasters. is this what you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the raster table to get row value, see link below (code is VBA not .NET but should give you a general e.g. of how to do it):

[How to access a raster table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000z3000000)

Answer (score 1):

Use your ArcObjects code to call on the built-in tools [Combine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Combine/009z0000007r000000/) and [Pivot Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Pivot_Table/0017000000n8000000/). You can combine two different rasters having the same classes that you wish to compare as shown [here](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/uploads/instructions/AVErrorMatrix.pdf), and *before* pivoting, add two new text fields to calculate strings for the class values that correspond to InRas1 and InRas2.